# Check if palindrome can be formed

Tags: algorithm

Given a string S how can we check that weather we can convert it to palindrome or not by just changing one single letter. Please help a fast solution to do it.

Example : Let us have S = "mixem". Then the answer is YES as we can change "e" to "i" to make it palindrome.

String of length can be 1000 at max.

Comment: Where is the code you have tried? Have you tried to implement it. Haven't you?

Comment: @nanndoj Yeah I have. But I want a code that can execute in half of a second. I had tried to change each letter with letter on opposite side..But it is very ineficient

Comment: I'm not your downvoter. But this is the kind "do it for me" question that is a strong candidate to downvote. I think the best way is to provide your code and ask for help in some specific point you want to improve!

Comment: `is_almost_palindrome = letters_not_in_common(s, reversed(s)) <= 2`. Implementing `letters_not_in_common` and `reversed` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 0-based indexing, it suffices to check, for each `0 <= i < your_string_length`, if the number of positions for which the characters at positions `i` and `your_string_length - i - 1` are different is at most 2. If yes then the answer is also yes, otherwise it's not.

Basically, this checks how many pairs of characters with equal distance from the sides of the string are different: if only one such pair is different, then we can change one of its characters and make it equal. If more pairs, then we'd need to change more characters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your example correctly it means that you can change a single letter to ANY other letter. This makes the algorythm embarrassingly simple. You need to parse the word from sides into center and calculate number of mistakes. If it is <=1 then you can convert into a palindrome with 1 change or it is already a palindrome.

```
var s = "mixen", errors = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < s.length/2; i++){
 if(s[i] != s[s.length-1-i]){
  errors++;
 }
var isPalindrom = errors == 0;
var isPalindromConvertible = errors <= 1;
```

PS. You didn't specify language, so i've written in most convenient for me now: javascript